# Access configuration object (appsettings.json) in library project

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, configuration, appsettings

I started a .net core web api project.
I have one solution with the main project and many other project like DAL, Common etc.

I want to create a class in the Common project that will share configuration settings(appsettings.json) between my different library project.
So, How can I acces Iconfiguration from that class ?

Is this a good way to do this ? Or should I create a class into the main project to get configuration data from other project ?

Comment: Have a look at [options pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it would be to create a Configuration Model based on your section/subsection from your appsettings.json file, add the configuration section in your Startup.cs class, then you can use the built-in dependency injection to inject the configuration anywhere you would need it.

For Example

appsettings.json :

```
{
  "MyConfiguration" : {
     "Configuration1" : "1",
   }
}
```

Your configuration model:

```
public class MyConfiguration 
{
   public int Configuration1 { get; set; }
}
```

Then in the StartupClass in the ConfigureServices method you have to add

```
services.Configure<MyConfiguration>(configuration.GetSection("MyConfiguration"));
services.AddOptions();
```

And when you want to use that Configuration somewhere in the code, you would just inject it in the constructor like so:

```
public class SomeClass 
{
  private MyConfiguration MyConfiguration { get; }

  public SomeClass(IOptions<MyConfiguration> myConfigurationOptions)
  {
    MyConfiguration = myConfigurationOptions.Value;
  }

//... more code
}
```

Then you can access it

```
MyConfiguration.Configuration1
```

Comment: Yeah, I think his is the way i'm gonna follow even if I wanted to do this another way :)

Answer (score 0):

You can add the file `as a link` in yout project.

1. Right click your project , then select `"Add" ->"Existing Item..."`
2. Choose the file that you want to add to the solution
3. Instead of hitting Enter or clicking the Add button, you need to click the 
   **down-arrow icon at the right edge of the Add button**, and select "`Add As Link`".

Please refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22785729/12884742).